# How to remove over stain from finished woodwork on my stairs

Tags: stain, removal, stain-removal

We recently had our wood floors refinished and the floor guys carelessly got the water based stain on my wood casework. The casework is stained and finished with a glossy poly of some kind. I can't seem to get the stain off with acetone (does nothing)I had only planned to touch up my existing woodwork but now fear I may need to completely refinish it.

Comment: Do you know the specific product which was applied to the floor?  What kind of finish is on the casework?

Comment: They used Bona products for the satin Poly finish. I do not remember the brand of stain they used but do know it is water based. My casework has a glossy finish and are stained. The house is a 1985 Richmond house and all my woodwork is stained with a glossy finish.